# My Java method isnt handling errors. it states the error, but the next time the method is called it doesn't work properly anymore

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
public void move(){
    io.writeOutput(name + " kies een positie om een pion naar te verplaatsen (Maximaal 1 vakje) bijv AB = A naar B ");  
    s = io.readInput();

    if((s.length()==2)){
        c = s.charAt(0);
        k = s.charAt(1);
        System.out.println("correct lenght");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("incorrect length, try again");
        move();

    }


    if((s.length()==2)&&(c >= 'A' && c<= 'X')&&(k >= 'A' && k<= 'X')){
        if(board.getGameMap(c).getStatus().equals(color) && board.getGameMap(k).getStatus().equals(".") && BoardGeometry.areConnected(c,k)){
            board.getGameMap(c).setStatus(".");
            board.getGameMap(k).setStatus(color);
            System.out.println("pawn placed");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("invalid move");
                move();
        }   
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("choose a valid input");
        move();
    }
}
```

the 2nd time this piece of code is called (if the first time around I produced the "incorrect length") it doesn't work like it should and gives me both the "pawn placed" output AND the "invalid move" output.
It should only give me one of both.

Comment: Ugh, this is recursive, and shouldn't be.

Comment: Can you explain please? im new and i cant find my answer in other questions

Comment: You should use a loop to call `move` repeatedly. Right now you call `move` from *within* `move` when there's an input error, so it's recursive. While this will likely work (e.g., you won't blow the stack since valid input should come fairly quickly), it's not a great use case for recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time `s.length() != 2`, you will fall into both `else` statements.  You are calling `move()` twice in that case.

This is modified to call `move()` only once on a failure.

```
if(s.length()==2){
    c = s.charAt(0);
    k = s.charAt(1);
    System.out.println("correct length");

    if((c >= 'A' && c<= 'X')&&(k >= 'A' && k<= 'X')){
        if(board.getGameMap(c).getStatus().equals(color) && board.getGameMap(k).getStatus().equals(".") && BoardGeometry.areConnected(c,k)){
            board.getGameMap(c).setStatus(".");
            board.getGameMap(k).setStatus(color);
            System.out.println("pawn placed");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("invalid move");
            move();
        }      
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("choose a valid input");
        move();
    }
}
else{
    System.out.println("incorrect length, try again");
    move();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i still encounter a problem with this code tho. If my String s.lenght = 1 it will still go on with the method and generate an error when (k >= 'A' && k<= 'X') occurs because k = the 2nd character of my string k = s.charAt(1);

Comment: If your `s.length == 1`, you will fall into the `incorrect length, try again`.  This will skip `if((c >= 'A' && c<= 'X')&&(k >= 'A' && k<= 'X')){`